# How can I return a string with the tags still in it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I tried this as a simple test:

```
@functions {
 private MvcHtmlString helloWorld()
 {
    return Html.EditorFor(m => m.Work.Description);
 }
}
<script type="text/javascript">console.log(@helloWorld().ToString());</script>
```

However, the generated html that shows up is in the form of

```
&lt;input class=&quot;text-box single-line&quot; id=&quot;Work_Description&quot;
name=&quot;Work.Description&quot; type=&quot;text&quot; value=&quot;&quot; /&gt;
```

How can return a string which is the form of

```
<input class="test-box single-line" id="Work_Description" name="Work.Description"
type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: At the return line of all `MvcHtmlString` functions, use:  `return MvcHtmlString.Create(stringValue);`

Comment: @Tohid - That is not the case here as the `Html.EditorFor` returns an `MvcHtmlString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@Html.Raw`. Be aware that if helloWorld().ToString() contains dangerous code, it could be a security problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">console.log(@Html.Raw(helloWorld().ToString()));</script>
```

Comment: Cool, this works perfectly, thank you. I will take care to secure the input. However, I would point out that in modern browsers such as Chrome a malicious user can inject `<script>` as they feel into the page after it has been rendered and even edit a `<form>`'s post action. In this regard, it seems likely that if there were a security risk it would be there regardless of using `Html.Raw`. Do you have an example of how `Html.Raw` could be used maliciously and in a way which could not be done with a simple injection?

Comment: I am not a security expert, but I know that if you take input directly from the user (like from a comment section on the page) and then output that content back to the page using @Html.Raw, it will be a security problem.  The user will be able to enter any script and have that script execute on your page for all users who view it.  Regarding your comment about browsers allowing users to inject into the page, this will just allow them to inject into the page rendered on their own browser, not other user's browsers or the server so it's not really a security risk.

Comment: Good point. But it would be pretty foolish to output user input which would allow for injections like that :)

Comment: This doesn't work when attempting to use a DropDownFor because the options all come on new lines, which causes an error in the javascript. Any ideas on how to encapsulate the returned string if it contains newlines?

Comment: I'm not a JavaScript person so I'm afraid I can't help you there. Perhaps post another question to address that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin is correct. Another thing to look at in the [AllowHtml] attribute in your model for the property, as well as using AntiXSSLibrary for cross site attacks. A great video can be found here: http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer.aspx?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-security&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro